# iPhone restarts whenever a call is made

Tags: iphone, itunes, call, restart

I updated my iPhone yesterday and now whenever I take or make a call my phone restarts itself.

It was updated via iTunes on my computer. Each phone call can last between 1 - 10 minutes.
I've never had this problem before.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? What version sis you update from? What model of iPhone do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like either a bug or the update didn't work properly.

That said, you should re-apply the update using [these instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) from Apple support.